# How can I stop Powershell filtering from converting my array to string?

Tags: powershell

Observe this example:

```
PS C:\> $list=("A","B")
PS C:\> $list.GetType().Name
Object[]
PS C:\> ($list | ? {$_ -ne "C"}).GetType().Name
Object[]
PS C:\> ($list | ? {$_ -ne "B"}).GetType().Name
String
```

Why on earth is Powershell converting my array to a String when there's only one element left? It breaks further processing of the variable in my script where I assume the output is an Array. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Force it to be an array with `@(..)`

Comment: I changed line 1 to be `$list=@("A","B")` but that didn't help.

Comment: Ah, `@($list | ? {$_ -ne "B"}).GetType().Name` works. Write that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain why Powershell seemingly converts an array to a string is caused by the result of `Where-Object / %`'s filtering and data it returns.

When the first version filters elements not equal to "C", the result is a collection. There were more than one matching member: "A" and "B". Thus, a collection is needed to contain both values.

The second version returns just a single object, "A", and thus it's a string instead of a collection. Since there is just a single object, there is no need to return an array with one element - just the object itself.

Theo's answer works by making `Where-Object`'s output to be an array. The [array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) `@()` can be used to create arrays. Like so,

```
# Convert where-object's output into an array,
# even if there is only a single object.
@($list | ? {$_ -ne "B"})
```

Comment: Could you please include Theo's answer as your own answer so that when people visit this question they don't need to look up references?

Answer (score 2):

To complement my comment and [vonPryz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67263783/9898643)

PowerShell 'unravels' one-element arrays when returning from a function or scriptblock into a single scalar, in this case a string.

To prevent that from interfering with the rest of the code which expects an array, no matter if it is empty or has only one element, you can force the output to become an array by wrapping it inside `@()`.

In your case,

```
($list | ? {$_ -ne "B"})
```

would return the single element `A`, turned into a scalar `String`, while

```
@($list | ? {$_ -ne "B"}).GetType().Name
```

returns an array (`Object[]`) with just one element in it.

Answer (score 0):

While what the other two answers say *usually* works, it won't work in *all* cases.

Take, for example, this case:

```
@(
    @('single-element-array') | 
        ForEach-Object { "$_".Trim() } |
        Sort-Object -Unique
) | ConvertTo-Json
```

The result will simply be:

```
"single-element-array"
```

First, that code above looks silly, but, assume that you had queried for some data and the result was a single element array, whose element may consist of whitespace or is `$null`, and you wanted to ensure that the value collapses to `''`, hence the `"$_".Trim()`. OK, with that out of the way, the resulting JSON is probably not what one would expect coming from other programming languages such as C#.

Much as described by the other answers, since this expression flows through a pipeline, the same rules as described by others apply, and the resulting object is "unwrapped".

Typically, a function implements a pipeline as follows:

```
function Some-Function {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]] $InputObject
    )

    Begin {
        # This block is optional
    }

    Process {
        # This block is optional, too, but is required
        # to process pipelined objects

        foreach ($o in $Object) {
            # do something
        }
    }

    End {
        # This block is optional IF a Process block
        # is defined.

        # If no Begin, Process, or End blocks are defined,
        # the code after the parameters is assumed to be
        # an End block, which effectively turns the function
        # into a PowerShell 2.0 filter function.

        # When data is piped into this function, and a Process
        # block exists, the value of $InputObject in this block
        # is the very last item that was piped in.
        # In cases where the pipeline is not being used, $InputObject
        # is the value of the parameter as passed to the function.
    }
}
```

To use the above:

```
$Stuff | Some-Function
```

In a function like this, using the pipeline, values are processed *serially*. Each value in `$Stuff` is piped into the function. If the function has a `Begin` block, that runs once, before any value is processed from parameters passed in via the pipeline, i.e. other non-pipelined parameter values are available in the `Begin` block. The `Process` block is then executed *once* for each value pipelined in. Finally, if the function has an `End` block, that is run at the very end after all values piped in have been processed.

So, why use a `foreach` statement in the `Process` block? To handle when the function is called thusly:

```
Some-Function -InputObject $Stuff
```

In this invocation, the entire array of `$Stuff` is passed by parameter to the function. So, in order to process the data correctly, a `foreach` loop in the `Process` block is used. And this should now give you the information you need to know how to circumvent the problem in my first example. In order for that example to run correctly, it needs to be done as follows:

```
ConvertTo-JSON -InputObject @(
    @('single-element-array') |
        ForEach-Object { "$_".Trim() } |
        Sort-Object -Unique
)
```

And this results in the expected JSON:

```json
[
  "single-element-array"
]
```

Hope that helps to clarify the issue.